# Maven and copying at test time

Tags: maven, junit, maven-3

How can I have maven copy some resource files from another project right before the junit test cases are run?

I want this because the json files are maintained by the ui team for their testing purposes, so I want to use those same files to run against our layers so that we know we don't break the expected output when we change our code.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the maven dependency plugin to selectively "unpack" the files from the project which has those files.

For example say the project in which the resource file is **com.foo.bar:myArtifact:jar**, so you can do something like

```
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>unpack</id>
                <!-- You could a phase of your choice based on needs -->
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>unpack</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                      <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
                      <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
                      <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                      <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                      <includes>*.json</includes>
                    </artifactItem>
                  </artifactItems>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
```

This will copy all .json files (just an example) to the current project's build output directory.

 You can refer to the dependency plugin for more configuration options.

 Hope this helps.

Comment: What if the project I want to copy from is built after the project I want to copy too.

Comment: @arinte First of all it would not be a good practice to depend on a project which is built after a certain project.
Still if there is a need, you can either link the files at the other project (symlinks) or if they belong to the same source tree, you can reference then using a relative path like ${basedir}/../some-project-built-after-me/src/main/resources/...